# Spring boot application not identifying controller and repository beans

Tags: spring-boot

I have this project structure

```
com.demo.application
    - DemoApplication.java


@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
                System.out.println("inside main");
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

I have another package

```
com.demo.application.employee
   - EmployeeController.java
   - EmployeeInterface.java
   - Employee.java (Entity Bean)

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/getAll")
public class EmployeeController {

    @Autowired
    EmployeeInterface empInterface;

    public ModelAndView getEmployees() {
        System.out.println("inside controller");
        return new ModelAndView("employee", "employee", empInterface.findAll());
    }
}

@Repository
    public interface EmployeeInterface extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long>{

    }
```

When i access the below URL i get 404. The reason is the Controller and Repository beans are not loaded.

```
http://localhost:8080/getAll
```

Any help?

Comment: Anything wrong with my package structure? Am i missing some annotations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `getAll` does not associated with any controller handler.

Add `@RequestMapping` to your `getEmployees()` method:

```
@RequestMapping
public ModelAndView getEmployees() {
```

But it's not very intuitive. You should annotated your controller with the base path and your method with specific path:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/employee")
public class EmployeeController {

    @Autowired
    EmployeeInterface empInterface;

    @RequestMapping("/getAll")
    public ModelAndView getEmployees() {
        System.out.println("inside controller");
        return new ModelAndView("employee", "employee", empInterface.findAll());
    }
}
```

Now your URL looks like: `localhost:8080/employee/getAll`